# Solving optimisation sub-instances in Parallel, using Pyomo ( Traceback )

Tags: parallel-processing, solver, decomposition, pyomo

I am trying to solve an energy model with Benders Decomposition.

In the model we are creating a master model and several sub models.

And I want to solve the sub models in parallel, and I saw an example [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/benders/runbenders).

This is what I am using in the code:

```
from pyomo.opt.base import SolverFactory
from pyomo.opt.parallel import SolverManagerFactory
from pyomo.opt.parallel.manager import solve_all_instances

subs = []
for m in range(0, len(supportsteps)-1):
    subs.append(urbs.create_model(data,
                        range(supportsteps[m], supportsteps[m+1]+1),
                        supportsteps, type=1))

solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory("pyro")

solve_all_instances(solver_manager, 'gurobi', subs)
```

Which gives an error:

[image]
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQgVE.png)

So what I am doing wrong?

Or, is it not possible to solve them in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message that you're seeing means that `SolverManagerFactory("pyro")` gave you `None`. It's possible that `pyro` isn't installed or on your PATH.

Try installing the Pyomo extras: `conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.extras` or `pyomo install-extras`

Comment: Aight, I am gonna check. Till then I am marking this question, as answered^^. TY